# I want to extend my root partition using 2 unallocated partitions but one it to the left and other is to the right. How do i do it.?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 22.04, gparted, swap

I want to extend my root partition, using 2 unallocated partitions, but one if present to the left of the root, and another if present in the right.

The sequence is :
Unall | ROOT | Linux-Swap | Linux-Swap | Unallocated

Heres the screenshot of Gparted
[Gparted Partitions Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pql48.png)

Can anyone explain me how can I do this. I saw a tutorial but it has only one linux swap partition. Also I want to ask that the second swap partition isnt using any space so can I just delete it and merge it with the unallocated space.? I can provide the output of any commands if needed.

Comment: Yes, but first create good backups of everything on drive, including Windows, Ubuntu & data partitions. The move left will take a while and any interruption totally corrupts data as it is half moved. You have to use live installer to make sure partitions are unmounted. Once that is done check that system boots ok before next steps. You should go into fstab and comment out swaps with # and then from live installer remove swaps & then expand right. You can create one new swap of 4.1GB. Then update fstab with new UUID of new swap partition.  Do each step separately. Post any errors in question.